# BitBake: Can we use DEPENDS with package name?

Tags: dependencies, yocto, bitbake

From BitBake User Manual, I know that when using RDEPENDS, we should always use the variable in a form with an attached package name, for example: RDEPENDS_${PN} += "a" 
Can we do the same for DEPENDS variable ? Like: DEPENDS_${PN} += "b" 
I got this question because when I put this into my recipe, BitBake do not raise any error, but my build sometime failed due to it cannot handle the dependecies.

Comment: Please post build log error when it fails?

Comment: I cannot put the log here, but the error happen due to compiler cannot find the dependency libraries when linking: ld: cannot find -l<lib>, which were built by recipe b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DEPENDS is about compile time dependencies. The results of a single compile can be used in multiple packages so making the variable package-specific is not possible: DEPENDS is always used for the whole recipe and cannot be postfixed with a packagename.

Comment: Thank you for answering. If we cannot use DEPENDS with a package name, why does BitBake not raise an error/warning for this ?

Comment: You are just defining a completely new variable: nothing uses that variable but Bitbake can't really know that this should be an error.